# find . -type f in ruby

Tags: ruby, glob, directory

I want to grab a list of all the files under a particular directory.  Dir.glob works great, but there doesn't seem to be a way to limit results to just files (excluding directories).

Heres's what I have right now:

```
files = Dir.glob('my_dir/**/*').reject { |f| File.directory?(f) }
```

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually a fairly efficient way to go about doing it, but you might also use the Find module:

```
require 'find'

found = [ ]

Find.find(base_path) do |path|
  found << path if (File.file?(path))
end
```

Comment: +1: I always forget about the `find` library, but it is indeed the most efficient (in terms of programmer time, anyway) way to port a POSIX `find` expression to Ruby.